# Sharepoint REST API with Azure AD oauth2 authentication for simple users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I  am trying  to access from  my  server to  files  on sharepoint  sites with  Azure  AD   oauth2, i  created  multi-tenant Azure  AD   app  with  such permissions

[image: My Azure AD app permissions]

after this  i am going  through standard  oauth2  process  to  obtain tokens:

i  redirect user to https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123XXXXXXXXf4d5d4512&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FdXXXXXXX%2Foffice365_oauthcallback.html
and  when  admin  user  log  in then  everything  is  going  smoothly, but  ordinary  user  can not  log in, he  is  getting:

> Additional technical information:
>
> Correlation ID: d81a1cca-1c4f-4da1-9162-88ba74d57775
>
> Timestamp: 2015-07-01 09:49:53Z
>
> AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator.
>   Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your
>   organization's administrators.

i  assume  that  he  is  getting  this  because  can not  use  some  permissions

may  same  one  help  me  to  choose   correct  permissions  which  will  allow  to  me  to  authorize  with  Azure  AD  oauth2  ordinary  user,  not  admin  only.

I  was  trying  to remove  access to Azure permission  from  app  and  leave  access  to  sharepoint  only, but  as  result  I   am getting

> AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000". This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.%0d%0aTrace ID%3a 97d7ddff-0eaf-487c-83be-e277970f9339%0d%0aCorrelation ID%3a dcf33c54-fb51-46d9-9ee5-09db8d425b0d%0d%0aTimestamp%3a 2015-07-01 09%3a58%3a05Z

i  was  trying  to  follow  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/088c7f00-70ae-47ac-abe6-bdf6b5778468/aadsts65005-the-request-has-failed-because-the-client-has-not-specified-this-resource-in-its?forum=WindowsAzureAD  and  put  &resorce=  param  as  sharepoint  site

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123ae4***5d4512&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FdXXXXXXX%2Foffice365_oauthcallback.html&resource=https://SITE.sharepoint.com/DP/

and  as  result i  got this

> AADSTS50001: Resource https://SITE.sharepoint.com/DP/ is not
>   registered for the account. Trace ID:
>   b30da866-5a89-4962-9617-92a7cfe649b9 Correlation ID:
>   48a5ef84-8211-4588-8339-05ba7154fbc6

I put   &resorce=  param  as  sharepoint  site DOmain

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123ae4***5d4512&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FdXXXXXXX%2Foffice365_oauthcallback.html&resource=https://SITE.sharepoint.com

and  got

> Additional technical information: Correlation ID:
>   7f006d85-a72a-480f-b92e-0c706190f73e Timestamp: 2015-07-01 10:13:17Z
>   AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator.
>   Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your
>   organization's administrators.

what i  am  doing  wrong?  is  there  are  any  way to  make  oauth2  through Azure AD   for  ordinary  user,  not  just  for  admin?

Comment: I   found  answer:  http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/06/08/aadsts90093-calling-principal-cannot-consent-due-to-lack-of-permissions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found  answer on this   page http://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/06/08/aadsts90093-calling-principal-cannot-consent-due-to-lack-of-permissions/  it  contains  all  permissions  you   may  set  for  AD  App which  do not  require  admin  permissions  to  been  accepted.